# Jquery Only working when I reload the page - Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have an issue with my Javascript not working in Firefox.

I'm fetching images for a page from external sources (IP cameras). Where I am unable to fetch an image, I want to serve my own placeholder image so I don't show the browser default broken image. The solution I have works perfectly in Chrome. However, in Firefox it is automatically loading the missing image - but if I refresh the page it then works perfectly.

The code is:

```
    $(function () {
       // Replace Broken Image
       $('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'https://www.evercam.io/img/error.png ');
       });
    });
```

Does any one know why this wouldn't work in Firefox?

Cheers,
Ciarán

Answer (score 1):

it about event binding use on/live instead.

https://api.jquery.com/on/

basicly what happens is it only bind event to imgs already there for more check JS event delegate.

try `$(document).on("error", "img", func...);`

basically document can be anything (selector, or object) that is a parent of actually element that triggers the event. what happen is with the event bubbling parent click event also get triggered and in the event jquery checks the trigger has given selector.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Onur, Thanks for the link. I've gone through that and changed my code to this:
    `$(function () {
        $( "img" ).on( "error", function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://www.evercam.io/img/error.png ");
        });
    });` 

but I still can't seem to get it to fix my problem. Have I used the .on correctly?